# c++ calling a non static function from a static function

Tags: c++, windows

I'm experiencing an access violation error when I try to call non static function.

my `.h` file looks like this.

```
class World
{
public:
    World();
    virtual ~World();
    static void CALLBACK DispatchCallback(
        SIMCONNECT_RECV *pData,
        DWORD cbData,
        void *pContext
    );
    void Process(SIMCONNECT_RECV *pData, DWORD cbData);
    virtual void frameEvent();
    virtual void init();
};
```

Now in my .cpp file the init() function I call a function that return data to my callback function.

```
SimConnect_CallDispatch(hSimConnect, DispatchCallback, NULL);
```

Which sends data to the `DisPatchCallback` function.

In this function the following code resides:

```
void CALLBACK World::DispatchCallback(
    SIMCONNECT_RECV *pData,
    DWORD cbData,
    void *pContext)
{
    World *pThis = reinterpret_cast<World*>(pContext);
    pThis->Process(pData, cbData);
}
```

this function is a static function which creates a World object to call the Process function.

This works but it break on the line where it wants to access the frameEvent function.

```
void World::Process(SIMCONNECT_RECV *pData, DWORD cbData)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    switch(pData->dwID)
    {
    case SIMCONNECT_RECV_ID_EVENT_FRAME:
        frameEvent(); //it breaks here frameEvent is a non static function
        break;
    }
}
```

> Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Can someone point me to the right direction as to solve this issue.?

If you wonder I'm writing a plugin for Microsoft Flight Simulator X.

I'm trying to implement `simconnect.h` in a oo way. Msdn shows an example that I'm trying to implement.

```
class CName
{
    void Dispatch();
    static void DispatchCallback(
        SIMCONNECT_RECV *pData,
        DWORD cbData,
        void *pContext
    );
    void Process(SIMCONNECT_RECV *pData, DWORD cbData);

    HANDLE hSimConnect; // use SimConnect_Open to set this value.
};

void CName::Dispatch()
{
    ::SimConnect_Dispatch(hSimConnect, &CName;::DispatchCallback, this);
}

// static function
void CName::DispatchCallback(
    SIMCONNECT_RECV *pData,
    DWORD cbData,
    void *pContext)
{
    CName *pThis = reinterpret_cast<CName*>(pContext);
    pThis->Process(pData, cbData);
}

void CName::Process(SIMCONNECT_RECV *pData, DWORD cbData)
{
    // do processing of SimConnect data
}
```

I hope I gave enough information.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with static functions with context? And, in general, using `casts` in such a way indicates bad desing...

Comment: @Griwes: This is actually a very common pattern when writing C++ code with C APIs -- you pass in `this` as a context parameter along with a `static` callback function, which forwards the callback into a class method on the object.  It's used with window procedures, thread procedures, library callbacks, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're passing `NULL` as the context parameter to `SimConnect_CallDispatch`, so your callback has no idea which `World` object to call `Process` on -- how could it possibly if you don't tell it?  Change the call to pass in `this` as the context parameter, like the example does:

```
SimConnect_CallDispatch(hSimConnect, DispatchCallback, this);
```

Comment: Thanks im a bit ashamed that i overlooked on that its so abvious!

Answer (score 2):

It breaks because `this` is NULL.

Check this portion of your code:

```
World *pThis = reinterpret_cast<World*>(pContext);
pThis->Process(pData, cbData);
```

If the `reinterpret_cast` <strike>fails</strike> *gets a NULL* - it returns NULL, and you don't check for it.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` can't "fail" -- either it compiles or it doesn't. If `pThis` is null, then `pContext` **must** also be null.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of:

```
SimConnect_CallDispatch(hSimConnect, DispatchCallback, NULL);
```

seems very suspicious. What's the `NULL` parameter mean in the call to that function? Is that `pContext`?